# php: graph api in canvas page causing server error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, server-error

Im having following issue please help me out.

Im trying to request page details via graph api with page_id only.
And as far as I know I don't need a access token for this call. following is my code.

```
$graphApi = $facebook->api('/' . $data['fb_page_id'], 'GET');
```

Which above works fine locally, however when i upload to facebook and check out canvas page it give me blank page.

after debug i get this error

> Server error
>   The website encountered an error while retrieving (my canvas url). It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

and once i remove the graph api everything return back to normal.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright still dont know why is graph api causes server error, but got another solusion now. Reason i want to get the page details is that i just want the link to app page so instead of using api call i used the following url to get the link.

"http://www.facebook.com/pages/view/yourpageid" that will redirect to the page link.

hope this will help some people out!